# Pass a variable to popen command

Tags: c, linux, terminal, openssl, popen

I need to pass a string variable to a popen command that I made for decripting a piece of encrypted data. The code segment I need to use is:

```
char a[]="Encrypted data";
popen("openssl aes-256-cbc -d -a -salt <a-which is the data i have to pass here>","r");
```

What should I do to pass this variable into the command. I tried with:

```
popen("openssl aes-256-cbc -d -a -salt %s",a,"r");
```

But on compiling showed error that popen is passed too many arguments. Please help. Thanks in advance.
Operating Platform: Linux

Answer (score 5):

Use `snprintf` to construct the command string passed to popen.

```
FILE * proc;
char command[70];
char a[]="Encrypted data";
int len;
len = snprintf(command, sizeof(command), "openssl aes-256-cbc -d -a -salt %s",a);
if (if len <= sizeof(command))
{
    proc = popen(command, "r");
}
else
{
    // command buffer too short
}
```

Comment: Any specific reason to write a terminating NUL, when snprintf will do it?

Comment: Edited according to (appropriate) comments.

Comment: `snprintf` doesn't return -1 when the buffer's too short.. you need to compare its return to the buffer size as well, not just check for an error return.

Answer (score 2):

Constructing a command string with `snprintf` will break if the argument contains any spaces, quotes or other special characters.

On a Unix platform you should instead use `pipe` to create a pipe, then launch the subprocess with `posix_spawnp`, connecting the subprocess's stdout to the input end of the pipe with `posix_spawn_file_actions_adddup2`.